# How do I get the values under cursor instead of coords?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I get the value of a cell after clicking it? (`[9.00]` in the image)

Also, how do I change that bottom right value? (circled in red)

For example, if I wanted it to show a custom string, instead of `[9.00]`.

[image: bottomrightimshow]

Here is part of the code I tried, but I am only get xy coordinates this way:

```
def onpick3(event):
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    x = mouseevent.xdata
    y = mouseevent.ydata
    print(x)
    print(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
im, cbar = heatmap(df, list(range(1,16)), list(range(0,12)), ax=ax, cmap="YlGnBu")
texts = annotate_heatmap(im, valfmt="{x:.0f}")

fig.set_picker(picker=4)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)

plt.yticks(rotation=0) 
plt.xticks(rotation=30, horizontalalignment='left') 

plt.show()
```

The rest of the code is mostly the second example [here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)

Comment: You can get some event callbacks, https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html .  Not sure if you can get the item value.  You may need to write your own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This codes gets the value:

```
def onpick3(event):
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    x = int(mouseevent.xdata)
    y = int(mouseevent.ydata)
    value = df.loc[y][x]
    print(value)
```

Also found out how to modify the [coordinate formatter.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_zcoord.html)